# htaccess to redirect to dead links to 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-404

We recently migrated from one domain to another. We successfully redirected all valid URLs to their counterpart on the new site. However, there are quite a few links that were valid on the old domain that simply don't exist on the new domain. (e.g. pages/links that were outdated so we didn't migrate them)

For example, we had a blog component on the old domain that generated a lot of dynamic links like /blog/category/abc and /blog/tag/xyz. We no longer have this blog component on the new domain.

Using htaccess, what is the best way to make sure Google and other SE's are correctly aware that these pages/links no longer exist?

Answer (score 0):

The correct http status code to send is the 410 Gone code. To quote [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.11) (emphasis mine):

> The requested resource is no longer available at the server and no
>   forwarding address is known. This condition is expected to be
>   considered **permanent**. Clients with link editing capabilities
>   SHOULD delete references to the Request-URI after user approval. If
>   the server does not know, or has no facility to determine, whether or
>   not the condition is permanent, the status code 404 (Not Found) SHOULD
>   be used instead. This response is cacheable unless indicated
>   otherwise.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Can I mass redirect links that meet the criteria (e.g. /blog/tag/ ) to the 410 error using htaccess? If so, what would the proper redirect/rewrite be?

Comment: You don't redirect (that is, use a 301 or 302 status code to send the browser to a page) to serve a 410 status code. You can use the `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` directive in mod_alias with 'gone' as first argument. This will not actually cause a redirect to happen, but will serve the 410 status code. See http://serverfault.com/questions/104242/how-to-serve-410-from-apache-rather-than-a-404